# Recomendações de livros sobre a história da língua portuguesa

Tags: recursos, história

Lendo o livro Moderna Gramática Portuguesa, fiz uma anotação:

Galego-português IX-XII

Português arcaico XIII-XIV:

> Textos administrativos;
>
> Ajuda e Colocci Brancuti;
>
> Cantigas de Santa Maria;
>
> Livro das Aves, Fabulário de Esopo, Demanda do Santo Graal, Corte Imperial.

Português arcaico médio XV-XVI (1 ano):

> Livro da Montaria de D. João 1, Leal Conselheiro, Livro da Ensinança de Bem Cavalgar toda Sela de D. Duarte;
>
> Fernão Lopes;
>
> Zurara.

Português moderno XVI-XVII ou XVI-XVIII:

> João de Barros, Diogo do Couto, Fernão Lopes da Castanheda, Damião de Góis, Gaspar Correia, o Palmeirim de Inglaterra de Francisco de Morais, a Etiópia Oriental de Frei João dos Santos, Sá de Miranda;
>
> Antônio Ferreira (teatro), Imagem da Vida Cristã de Heitor Pinto, os Diálogos de Amador Arrais, os Trabalhos de Jesus de Tomé de Jesus e a Consolação às Tribulações de Israel, Peregrinação de Fernão Mendes Pinto, Pero Magalhães de Gandavo;
>
> LUIS DE CAMÕES;
>
> Said Ali;

Português Contemporâneo XVII(I)-hoje:

> Frei Luís de Souza;
>
> Sermões do Padre Antônio Vieira, os Apólogos Dialogais de Francisco Manuel de Melo,
> Padre Manuel Bernardes, Corte na Aldeia de Rodrigues Lobo;
>
> Pedro Antônio Correia Garção, Antônio Dinis da Cruz e Silva, Filinto Elísio, Tomás Antônio Gonzaga;
>
> Barbosa du Bocage.

Porém, gostaria de saber se há algum livro que explique melhor a história da língua portuguesa, mais detalhadamente. Principalmente, se possível, a fonologia e ortografia, pois eu adoro fonologia e ortografia.

Se possível, também recomendação de livros gratuitos e pagos.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Vi que suas referencias são mais relacionadas ao português antigo, entretanto nao poderia deixar de  recomendar sem dúvida o seguinte livro:

```
História da Língua Portuguesa
Capa comum: 584 páginas
Editora: Ateliê Editorial; Edição: 1 (25 de outubro de 2017)
ISBN-10: 8574803987
```

Comment: Podes colocar o link, por favor?